# Movement script relating to camera rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am rather new to unity and I have a script that works with my rigidbody that is attached to a sphere object. The problem is that the sphere does not move in the direction that my cinemachine camera is facing, it of course only moves in the direction that it has initially been set to. How do I get my sphere's WASD controls to act in the direction that the camera is facing?

Here is my movement script:

```
public class BallControl2 : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 2;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float movementHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float movementVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(movementHorizontal, 0.0f, movementVertical).normalized;

        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
        
    } }
```

Answer (score -1):

Vector3 position and direction refers to the world position and direction of your character, to move your character in the direction of camera you'll need a reference to your camera's transform and multiply your horizontal movement with camTranform.right and vertical movement with camTransform.forward

`Vector3 movement =  * camT.right * movementH +  camT.forward * movementV;`

~where movementH is your horizontal movement variable and camT is your camera's transform.~

Comment: This is going to sound dumb, but how to I reference my camera's transform?

Comment: You mean the correct thing but as you wrote it it wouldn't even compile ;) ... You probably ment `Vector3 movement =  * camT.right * movementH +  camT.forward * movementV;`

Comment: @BillMurray `yourCamera.transform.forward` etc?

Comment: This works brilliantly - I replaced the original vector3 line with Vector3 movement = Camera.main.transform.forward * movementHorizontal + Camera.main.transform.right * movementVertical;

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BillMurray you shouldn't do it that way though, please see the duplicate link! `Camera.main` is quite expensive